# Часть текста слева, часть справа внутри button CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

уважаемые пользователи. Столкнулся с проблемой описанной в заголовке.
Есть тэг button и внутри него надо сделать чтобы текст был слева, а иконка справа. Не мастер вёрстки и пол часа в гугле не дали результатов. Прошу экспертов о помощи.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i>Данные по продавцу</i><i class="material-symbols-outlined dop">store</i></button>
```

Предположил что разделив по тегам, как выше,  будет проще, но снова ничего не вышло. Ниже скрин того что сейчас получается если чем либо может помочь.
[image: Хочу чтобы иконка домика была справа]

UPD: Попросили добавить стили, думаю тоже поможет. Но там сейчас нет стилей выравнивания второго тэга i по правому краю, т.к. попытки не удались.

```
.analys-button button i {vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;}
```

У второго i есть класс dop, пытался через него ковырять, но как написал выше, ничего не вышло.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваши стили

Comment: Ставьте `flex` на кнопку и далее добавляете иконке `margin-left: auto;`

Comment: `.dop{float: right}`

Comment: @puffleeck спасибо, гений

Comment: @Vladimirbab0nStern, :3